# Variable result a result even after it was changed

Tags: python, variables

I'm making a text adventure game and have a variable holding the current location of the player. Outside the loop, it says location = b1. In the loop, the location can change. However, even after it has been changed, the script still prints the description for both locations - first the new location, then the old one again. The location changes after the player types "north".

```
location = b1
while alive:
    if location == b1:
        print("b1 location description")
        print("There is a door to the north and south.")
        print(idleActions)
        action = input("What would you like to do? ")
        if action == north:
            location = ha1
        if action == south:
            location = a1
        if action == west:
            print("To the west there is just a wall with paintings.")
        if action == east:
            print("east wall description")
        if action == inspect:
            print("What would you like to inspect?")
        if action == inspect + painting:
            print("painting stuff")
            print("painting stuff")


    if location == ha1:
        print("ha1 stuff")
        print("more ha1 stuff")
```

Comment: Your title and questions seem vague. Please be clear and specific and include input/output

Answer (score 0):

If I follow the game logic correctly, the prompt for answer should be outside `if` check. Below reproducible example, I've changed variables to literals just to test:

```
alive = 1
location = 'b1'
action = 'no_action_yet'
while alive:
    if location == 'b1':
        print("b1 location description")
        print("There is a door to the north and south.")
        print('idleActions')

        if action == 'north':
            location = 'ha1'
        if action == 'south':
            location = 'a1'
        if action == 'west':
            print("To the west there is just a wall with paintings.")
        if action == 'east':
            print("east wall description")
        if action == 'inspect':
            print("What would you like to inspect?")
        if action == 'inspect' + ' ' + 'painting':
            print("painting stuff")
            print("painting stuff")
        action = "no action"
    if location == 'ha1':
        print("ha1 stuff")
        print("more ha1 stuff")
    action = input("What would you like to do? ")
```

Comment: I have changed the code as you suggested, however it now asks for what you want to do before the location description. Also, the painting description doesn't work. Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: Just change the order of game events accordingly.

Comment: I've edited code, initial `action='no_action_yet'` was also added. Should work now as expected.

Comment: Thanks so much, this works now! Just curious, are the '' around the variables necessary?

Comment: Yes, since the variables values are not defined earlier in Your code

Comment: @DuckMcFuddle you can accept an answer by clicking the green check-mark next to the answer.